# A simple FOR /F isn't working with a string

Tags: command-line, script

Trying to execute the following script

```
FOR /F %%G IN ("Packages MNG RD") do echo %%G
```

Is only echoing the first parameter:

```
Packages
```

*tried to change the delims, played with tokens, but nothing helps.

Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using `/F` and qoutes, `FOR` is interpreting the string as one long filename. Changing the command slightly works for me:

```
for %%G IN (Packages MNG RD) do echo %%G
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%g in ("Packages MNG RD") do echo %%g
```

Tokens are delimited by spaces by default. `tokens=*` sets every token to the variable.